# How to read csv with multi row-column data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv files with thousands of records intended for import somewhere else and the format they're in is only easy to look at but not reading for importing. Here is a sample of the record structure:

[image: File 1]

These files have a single record with columns in multiple rows below them. As you can imagine, this is a bit tricky to read as one would expect one header for all records.

My question is, is this possible to read with pandas's `pandas.read_csv`?

I've tried [Reading this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation on parameters we can pass to `read_csv` but I can't see one that I can make use of.

if Pandas doesn't work for this kind of format, what would you recommend?

Comment: You could use pandas, but you're probably going to need to write some sort of iterative process to parse in chunks.  If you try posting the data in text format instead of a picture, we could possibly try to help.

Comment: Write your own parser. This is no where close to be [properly] read by pandas or csv. Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Reading file as text and then parsing data using regex can be an option.